# Placing footnotes on header and footer

Tags: formatting, footnotes, poetry

I need to print a poem which has a huge commentary. More or less, I will have three or four lines of text and the rest of the page will be filled by the commentary.

I am asked if it's possible to place the poem at the centre of the page, with the commentary running footnote-like on the header and on the footer.

Any ideas on how to set up my document?

Thank you,
A

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita

  mi ritrovai per una selva oscura

  che' la diritta via era smarrita.\footnote{\lipsum[1-6]}

Ahi quanto a dir qual era e` cosa dura

  esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte

  che nel pensier rinova la paura!\footnote{\lipsum[1-6]}

Tant'e` amara che poco e` piu` morte;

  ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,

  diro` de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.\footnote{\lipsum[1-6]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE as a starting point.  Otherwise I have to type in a poem and a bunch of footnote (I assume you would like to use real footnotes) before even starting on formatting it.

Comment: Could you please fix the orthography? ``diro` `` is wrong.

Comment: e` and  che' and piu` are wrong too!

Comment: By "centre of the page" are you talking horizontally, vertically or both.  Do you want the next section of poetry to start as soon as the commentary ends, or leave lots of white space?  Will you have multiple footnotes in one section of poetry, or multiple pages of commentary for one section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with modified output routine

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%% just for the example
\newcounter{mtctr}
\newcommand{\mtlipsum}[1][100]{%
\setcounter{mtctr}{0}%
\loop
\stepcounter{mtctr}%
\noindent this is line n \textbf{\themtctr}\par
\ifnum\value{mtctr}<#1 
\repeat}
%%%%%
\makeatletter
\gdef \@makecol {%  for normal pages
   \ifvoid\footins
     \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
       \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
       \ifdim\ht\@cclv<1ex
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \unvbox \footins
       \color@endgroup
       \unvbox \@cclv
       \else
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \vsplit\footins to .5\dimexpr\textheight-3\baselineskip\relax
         \vspace{\footnotesep}
         \footnoterule
       \color@endgroup
       \unvbox \@cclv
       \vspace{\skip\footins}
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \footnoterule
         \unvbox \footins
       \color@endgroup
       \fi}%
   \fi
   \let\@elt\relax
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
   \global \let \@midlist \@empty
   \@combinefloats
   \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \@texttop
       \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
       \unvbox \@outputbox
       \vskip -\dimen@
       \@textbottom
       }%
   \fi
   \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}
\def \@doclearpage {% special pages (here clearpage of end{document})
     \ifvoid\footins
       \ifvbox\@kludgeins
         {\setbox \@tempboxa \box \@kludgeins}%
       \fi
       \setbox\@tempboxa\vsplit\@cclv to\z@ \unvbox\@tempboxa
       \setbox\@tempboxa\box\@cclv
       \xdef\@deferlist{\@toplist\@botlist\@deferlist}%
       \global \let \@toplist \@empty
       \global \let \@botlist \@empty
       \global \@colroom \@colht
       \ifx \@currlist\@empty
       \else
          \@latexerr{Float(s) lost}\@ehb
          \global \let \@currlist \@empty
       \fi
       \@makefcolumn\@deferlist
       \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi{\@opcol\@makefcolumn\@deferlist}%
       \if@twocolumn
         \if@firstcolumn
           \xdef\@dbldeferlist{\@dbltoplist\@dbldeferlist}%
           \global \let \@dbltoplist \@empty
           \global \@colht \textheight
           \begingroup
              \@dblfloatplacement
              \@makefcolumn\@dbldeferlist
              \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi{\@outputpage
                                        \@makefcolumn\@dbldeferlist}%
           \endgroup
         \else
           \vbox{}\clearpage
         \fi
       \fi
     \else
       \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\box\@cclv\vfil}%
       \mt@makecol\@opcol
       \clearpage
     \fi
}
\gdef \mt@makecol {%
   \ifvoid\footins
     \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
       \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \unvbox \footins
       \color@endgroup
       \unvbox \@cclv
       }%
   \fi
   \let\@elt\relax
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
   \global \let \@midlist \@empty
   \@combinefloats
   \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \@texttop
       \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
       \unvbox \@outputbox
       \vskip -\dimen@
       \@textbottom
       }%
   \fi
   \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
An example for a LaTeX
An example for a LaTeX\footnote{\mtlipsum[90]}
An example for a LaTeXAn example for a LaTeX
An example for a LaTeX
An example for a LaTeX\footnote{\mtlipsum[80]}
An example for a LaTeXAn example for a LaTeX
An example for a LaTeX
An example for a LaTeX\footnote{\mtlipsum}
An example for a LaTeXAn example for a LaTeX
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me that you may not really want footnotes, you just want to put commentary around the poem, commentary which may not be closely tied to the page.  This is most easily done putting the poem into static frames then filling the flow frames with commentary.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{id}

\newflowframe[1-3]{\textwidth}{.4\textheight}{0pt}{.6\textheight}
\newflowframe[1-3]{\textwidth}{.4\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

\newcommand{\next}[1]% #1 = text for one page
{\stepcounter{id}%
\newstaticframe*[\theid]{.6\textwidth}{.1\textheight}{.2\textwidth}{.45\textheight}%
\setstaticcontents{\theid}{\parindent=\bibindent #1}}

\next{%
  Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita

  mi ritrovai per una selva oscura

  che' la diritta via era smarrita.
}
\next{%
  Ahi quanto a dir qual era e` cosa dura

  esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte

  che nel pensier rinova la paura!
}
\next{%
  Tant'e` amara che poco e` piu` morte;

  ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,

  diro` de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

Note that after the poem (and flow frames) end on page 3, one can continue the commentary on normal pages.

---

If you intend to tightly tie commentary to the poem, this is most easily done by putting the poem into dynamic frames and intermixing poem sections with commentary.  However, if the commentary runs over the end of the page, you will need to manually add gaps to the three page lists.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newdynamicframe*[1-3]{.6\textwidth}{.1\textheight}{.2\textwidth}{.45\textheight}[poem]
\newflowframe[1-3]{\textwidth}{.4\textheight}{0pt}{.6\textheight}
\newflowframe[1-3]{\textwidth}{.4\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

\newcommand{\next}[1]% #1 = text for one page
{\clearpage\setdynamiccontents*{poem}{\parindent=\bibindent\vfil #1}}

\begin{document}
\next{%
  Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita

  mi ritrovai per una selva oscura

  che' la diritta via era smarrita.
}
\lipsum[1]

\next{%
  Ahi quanto a dir qual era e` cosa dura

  esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte

  che nel pensier rinova la paura!
}
\lipsum[1-3]

\next{%
  Tant'e` amara che poco e` piu` morte;

  ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,

  diro` de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.
}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But I am afraid this way you have to manually arrange the commentary to get it corresponding to the main text.